# SQL MAX(m.time) does not select the highest value

Tags: sql, mysql

The piece of code:

```
SELECT m.message, 
          MAX(m.time) AS time, 
          m.sender, 
          m.receiver, 
          m.contact, 
          u.ufirstname
FROM( (SELECT message, 
                  receiver_uid AS receiver, 
                  sender_uid AS sender, 
                  time, 
                  receiver_uid AS contact 
             FROM messages 
            WHERE sender_uid = '$me' ) 
           UNION 
           (SELECT message, 
                   receiver_uid AS receiver, 
                   sender_uid AS sender, 
                   time, 
                   sender_uid AS contact 
              FROM messages 
             WHERE receiver_uid = '$me' ) ) AS m, 
         users AS u
   WHERE m.contact = u.uid
GROUP BY m.contact
ORDER BY time DESC;
```

My problem is that this piece SHOULD select the most recent message of a conversation.
This is the format of the database:

```
Sender_uid | receiver_uid | message | time («What format should this be?)
```

The first part retrieves all the messages in which '$me' (=userID of logged in user) takes part. So **all** the messages whether '$me' is sending or receiving.
The second part should select the most recent time (highest value) for each 'conversation' (=contact ID, whether contact is receiver or sender)

It **does not** get the most recent message. It **does** give you one message from the conversation.

**Important hint(?):** What I think the script is doing is retrieving the most recent message where '$me' is the sender.

I want it to collect the last message whether $me is receiver or sender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please stop abusing MySQL with mixing aggregates and non-aggregates. While MySQL allows it, it is unpredictable which records each column comes from, and they don't even have to be from the same record (in sync)

```
SELECT m2.message, 
          m2.time AS time, 
          m2.sender, 
          m2.receiver, 
          m.contact, 
          u.ufirstname
FROM (
    SELECT
        case when sender_uid = '$me' then receiver_uid else sender_uid end Contact,
        max(time) maxtime
    FROM messages 
    WHERE sender_uid = '$me' or receiver_uid = '$me'
    group by case when sender_uid = '$me' then receiver_uid else sender_uid end
) AS m
INNER JOIN messages m2 on m.maxtime = m2.time
    and ((m2.sender_uid = '$me' and m2.receiver_uid = m.Contact)
        or
        (m2.receiver_uid = '$me' and m2.sender_uid = m.Contact))
INNER JOIN users AS u on m.contact = u.uid
ORDER BY time DESC;
```

@updated query - was more complicated that it looked.

- The "Contact" is the other party of the conversation.
- The inner OR is used to pass through the table only once.
- The inner CASE statement is used to get the ID of the other party.
  If '$me' is matched to the sender, the receiver becomes the "contact"
  otherwise the sender is the "contact"
- The join with m2 uses 3 attributes - me, contact (either orientation) and maxtime
  This join uses the keys from the inner query (maxTime) to retrieve the
  full record from the table
- There is a final join with users to get the contact's firstname

Comment: Comment, not an answer.  But I completely agree about disliking MySQL (and SQLite's) "feature" about being able to omit GROUP BY clauses.  It's good for skilled SQL developers

Comment: I reformatted the notes at the bottom as bullets. It should explain how this works.